# Change Visio Shape Color OnClick Visio Services SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, visio-services

I have a Visio .vdw file saved to SP2010 Visio Web Access web part with Visio Services enabled. There is also a .js file embedded in a content editor web part which provides a single onclick functionality for shapes with hyperlinks.

The hyperlinks are connected to other shapes in the diagram. I also have a formula in the Visio ShapeSheet's EventDblClick field. The formula changes the color of the target shape's fill color to red when double clicked.

The formula works fine in Visio Designer but not in Visio Services. Is there a way to invoke EventDblClick field in a Visio Web Access web part? Can this be done with javascript?

**EventDblClick Formula:**

```
IF(FillForegnd=RGB(255,0,0),SETF(GetRef(FillForegnd),RGB(255,255,255)),SETF(GetRef(Pages[Pagename]!Sheet.ID!FillForegnd),RGB(255,0,0)))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you